# Search for values in 2 columns from CSV

Tags: grep, search, csv, cut, columns

I have a csv files with say 20 odd columns.

I need to get the 14th and 15th column values where value in 14th column is say `"VALUE1"` and value in 15th column is `"VALUE2"`.

My condition gets satisfied only when 14th column has `VALUE1` and 15th column has `VALUE2`. I need to get the aggregate count.

I think `wc -l` could give me the count list and 
`cut -d "," -f14,15` gives me the 14th and 15th column values. But how to check whether 14th has `VALUE1` and 15th has `VALUE2`?

I think the one below works

```
grep -r "" * | cut -d " " -f14,15 | grep "Value1" | grep "Value2"
```

but still I don't think this is the perfect way to do do it.

Comment: Fyi, you use different delimiters in your `cut` commands.

Comment: Your grep fails if you have "Value1Value2" in one of the 14th or 15th field.  The right way to do it would be to grep on "^Value1 Value2$"

Comment: @Ebbu please accept the answer which helped you to solve this issue so it will help others. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

`awk` could be more useful here.

For example:

```
$> echo "a b c d e" | awk '$2=="b" && $3=="c" {print}'
a b c d e

$> echo "a b c d e" | awk '$2=="a" && $3=="c" {print}'

$> echo "a b c d e" | awk '$2=="b" && $3=="d" {print}'
```

So answer to your question could be:

`awk '$14=="VALUE1" && $15=="VALUE2" {print}'`

Comment: I am sorry but awk is not installed. I am logged in as a remote user and installing awk is not possible.

Comment: @Ebbu, then you should add to your question what system you are using. That `awk` is not available seems a little bit unusual.

Comment: awk should always be available on Unix (as should be vi, contrary to perl, python and emacs).  It is part of the Unix Specification since POSIX (1991). See those for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification http://std.dkuug.dk/jtc1/sc22/open/n2972.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If `awk` is not available you can do it with `cut`, `grep` and `wc`:

```
$ echo -e 'a,b, c,d\na,val1 ,val2,c' \
   | cut -d ',' -f2,3 | grep '^ *val1 *, *val2 *$' | wc -l
```

Assuming `,` as delimiter (and no somehow escaped `,` is included) in the input. For testing purposes, the columns 2 and 3 are used instead of 14 and 15.

Note that the `grep` pattern allows trailing whitespace after/before the values (you can remove the `*` sub-patterns if you don't want that). The meta-characters `^` and `$` match the beginning and the end of a line.

The pipe `grep "Value1" | grep "Value2"` from you question does not do what you specify - it would match too much, e.g.:

```
    ..., Value1Value2, , ...
    ..., Value1, Value2, ...
    ..., OtherValue1, Value2, ...
    ...
```

If `awk` is available (it is pretty standard) you can do it like this:

```
$ echo -e 'a,b, c,d\na,val1,val2,c' \
    | awk -F, '$2 == "val1" && $3 == "val2" {++sum} END {print sum}'
```

`awk` automatically trims whitespace from the values. `END` is a specially pattern that matches after all lines are processed.

Answer (score 1):

The following function will use only **Bash** to do what you want:

```
foo () 
{ 
    local filename="$1";
    while IFS=, read -ra arr; do
        if [[ "${arr[13]}" = "VALUE1" && "${arr[14]}" = "VALUE2" ]]; then
            printf '%s\n' "${arr[13]}" "${arr[14]}";
        fi;
    done < "$filename"
}
```

**Usage:** foo [/path/to/file.txt]

**Sample output:**

```
rany$ cat > source.txt 
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,VALUE1,VALUE2
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,NOMATCH1,NOMATCH2
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,VALUE1,VALUE2

rany$ foo source.txt
VALUE1
VALUE2
VALUE1
VALUE2
```